# Can't read property 'id' of undefined angular 8 on ng serve on dev only. ng-serve --prod works fine

Tags: angularjs

I am getting this error when trying to run the project on dev environment using ng serve

Answer (score 0):

`ng serve --prod` must work fine since it renders static files. however, in the development server, you render from your SPA(angular project which includes `angular.json`, etc.) files.

However, the error you are getting is because some data you import(get)/define is `null` to solve this you need to check if the data you import(get)/define is available in the component.

eg: ts

```
public toys: number;

ngOnInit() {
    toys = 2;
}
```

HTML:

```
<h2>{{ toys }}</h2>  !!IMPORTANT(use correct spellings)
```